# Android/php Jsonobject error parsing

Tags: php, android, json, parsing

i have a problem with jsonObject.

in android app i have:

```
try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        Log.e("JSON Parser2", "json: "+json);
    }
```

the logcat is:

```
01-03 16:50:09.239: E/JSON Parser(17447): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject 
01-03 16:50:09.239: E/JSON Parser2(17447): json: [][][]{"code":0,"message":"Segnalazione inviata correttamente"}
```

in php i have:

```
$response = array();
$response["code"] = $e['code'];
$response["message"] = $e['message'];
echo json_encode($response);
```

thanks

Comment: `[][][]` are spurious in the json you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your [PHP JsonObejct](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) Creation Code as :

```
echo json_encode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

and now you can parse current json string as :

```
  String str_final_json=json.replace("{}{}{}","");   

 // convert string to jsonObject
 JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(str_final_json);

// get code from json object
String str_code=jObj.getString("code");

// get message from json object
String str_message=jObj.getString("message");
```

Comment: i suppose you mean  `String str_code=jObj.getString("code");`

Comment: but it don't work `01-03 17:16:29.039: W/System.err(20954): org.json.JSONException: No value for code` (same for message)

Comment: @Atomico : you have added `echo json_encode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);` in php file ?

Comment: @Atomico : now what json string you are getting from server?plz share with me

Comment: 01-03 17:26:36.889: E/JSON(21931): json: {}{}{}{"code":0,"message":"Segnalazione inviata correttamente"}

Comment: yeah it work... but i want know what is this {}{}{} that we need to delete :)

Comment: @Atomico : i'm not much good in PHP so you need to make a question about this why you are not getting right jsonobject or jsonarray in PHP section . if you get any solution then just comment `String str_final_json=json.replace("{}{}{}",""); ` and pass string to `JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);` directly

Comment: just for your curiosity.. i found the problem :) in the code i wrong put `echo json_encode($response, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);` more than 1 time.. my fault :)

Answer (score 0):

Use **[JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)** if your top level object is an array.

```
   try {
        jArr = new JSONArray(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        Log.e("JSON Parser2", "json: "+json);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess the issue is with your php code try to change your php code like below

```
$response = array("code" => $e['code'], "message" =>$e['message']);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: 01-03 17:32:29.279: E/JSON(21931): json: {}{}{}{"code":null,"message":null}

Comment: Try var_dump($e) and check if you get proper results.